# Что возвращает оператор input если ничего не ввести?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что возвращает оператор `input()` если ничего не ввести???

```
w = input ("Введите + или - : ")
if w == "+" or w == "-":
    print ("Вы что-то нажали")
elif w == ЧТО ТУТ НАПИСАТЬ Я НЕ МОГУ ПОНЯТЬ (это, если просто нажать enter, ничего не введя):
    print ("Вы нажали enter, ничего не введя, отлично!!!")
else:
    print ("Вы ничего не нажали, обидка")
```

Comment: Возвращает пустую строку `''`

Comment: @entithat он не возвращает пустую строку я перепробовал все такие варианты

Comment: А что он тогда возвращает? :)

Comment: @entithat я не знаю и хз как это найти XDXDXD

Comment: Боюсь спросить, как Вы тогда узнали, что он не возвращает пустую строку, если Вы даже не в курсе, как проверить возвращаемое значение?

Comment: Слово "ничего" пишется слитно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко проверить

```
s = input()
print(s, type(s)) # '', <class 'str'>
```

Ваш код:

```
w = input ("Введите + или - : ")
if w == "+" or w == "-":
    print ("Вы что-то нажали")
elif w == '':
    print ("Вы нажали enter ни чего не введя, отлично!!!") # при пропуске ввода будет это
else:
    print ("Вы ни чего не нажали, обидка")
```

Comment: хорошо но если я дам задачку по сложнее ща

Comment: @Shuvi  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Shuvi, задачку посложнее давайте отдельным вопросом. Если данный ответ решил Вашу проблему, описанную в этом вопросе, примите его как верный (зелёная галочка слева).

Comment: @all я понял что в этой задачке нет ошибки но я думал что если задам сразу со всем кодом то ждать ответа долго